# How does Custom Domain mapping work in MVC C#?

Tags: c#, url, model-view-controller, routes

I am developing a web application using MVC 5, C#. This is a SaaS application where each company has its unique URL at signup and that URL will become the link to its own portal where its members or customers can go to sign up, login and much more. I would like to be able to give those companies the ability to do Custom Domain Mapping where they can use their own existing domain in lieu of their automatically generated portal URL. All my research has been unsuccessful so far, even though I know applications that have those capabilities.
Please, help with any idea on how I can approach this.